# synchronizing pannel scrollbar and textbox scrollbar

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, scrollbar

On a Winform/C# application, I created a panel, on this pannel I added a `TextBox`.

I enable the horizontal pannel scrollbar, and I would like to be able to scroll my textbox using the pannel scrollbar ( and not the textbox scrollbar).

Is this possible ?

For the moment I did this :

```
panel1.HorizontalScroll.Enabled = true;
panel1.HorizontalScroll.Visible = true;
```

My scrollbar pannel is displayed but it doesn't scroll.

Answer (score 0):

AS [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.panel(v=vs.110).aspx) says:

> Used to group collections of controls.

I think you are trying use it as a "decoration", if that is the purpose, try extend textbox control and add that with other "draw" controls.